# Pentaho - transform two columns into a table with the first column as column name and the second as values

Tags: etl, pentaho, influxdb, business-intelligence, pentaho-data-integration

I’m new to pentaho.
I’ve made a rest call to an influx db, resulting into a json response.
From this response I have isolated two fields: columns and values.

For example:

Columns = [“name_column_1”,”name_column_2”,...,”name_column_n”]

Values = [[“value_column_1_1”,”value_column_2_1”,...,”value_column_n_1”], [“value_column_1_2”,”value_column_2_2”,...,”value_column_n_2”],..,]

How do I transform this into a table with column name the values into ‘Columns’ and with corresponding values the values into ‘values’?

(The column names are more than 500, impossibile to write by hand and they may change so I need a dynamic solution  )

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a krt file and use 2 components: Json input and table Output.

May be 2 links below will give you some idea:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSLI67ZCmxE&ab_channel=KPTechTalks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0xA9vyZc8w&ab_channel=BuxProjects

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the volume of data, this can get out of memory very quickly, so you'll probably need to split the process into different transformations, generating temporary files or tables with the data out of each transformation for the next one, but one way to achieve it would be:

First you'll need to use the step *Split field to rows* twice, to transform one incoming row into n rows with columns and values. Use the check to generate the rownum both for splitting Columns and Values, and after add a filter so rownum_for_column = rownum_for_value. You'll also need to clean up the brackets and " enclosures and maybe additional fields, without knowing your data I can only guess. This will generate for each row in your input n rows in your output with the pair NAME_COLUMN_N VALUE_N.

In the samples directory in your Pentaho Data Integration installation, you have a sample of how to work with Row denormaliser step (the name of the transformation with the example is **Denormaliser 2 series of key values pairs**). That step will allow you to pivot your rows into that type of information.

Now, having so many columns to denormalise, you'll need to inject metadata into the Row denormaliser step with that information, you'll need a transformation to extract the list of name_column_1, name_column_2, ..., and inject that information to the transformation with your Row denormaliser step. Check Pentaho oficial documentation on how to work with metadata injection (and check the samples for an example on how metadata injection works).